# Lightning Visualforce Page Error on Lead Object

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience

I try to edit lead in Lightning visualforce page, when i click save i get error like below. The URL in Lightning also changes to a long weird URL. Any recommendation?

> Review the errors on this page. This record was modified by x during
>   your edit session. Make a note of the data you entered, then reload
>   the record and enter your updates again.

Answer (score 0):

Can you throw more light on the issue?

By the description given above, I can see that you are experiencing the error while lead record is opened in Edit mode and you are saving.

Currently SF(lightning experience) gives a lengthy URL whenever it navigates to VF page. we cannot get rid of that.

I just checked updating the lead from VF is working as expected.

Can you tell us when exactly that error is popping up?

Comment: when the lead record is open in an edit mode (VF) PAGE , If i click save$new on the page then the error pops up